# How do I declare a C# anonymous type without creating an instance of it?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Is there a better way that can I declare an anonymous type, without resorting to create an instance of it?

```
var hashSet = new [] { new { Name = (string)null } }.Take(0).ToHashSet(); // HashSet<T>
using (new Scope())
{
    hashSet.Add(new { Name = "Boaty" });
    hashSet.Add(new { Name = "McBoatface" });
}
using (new AnotherScope())
{
    return names.Where(x => hashSet.Contains(new { x.Name }));
}
```

I dislike the hacky-looking approach taken in the first line above, but it does allow me to use the HashSet from within different scopes later.

EDIT:
A second, slightly more comprehensive, example:

```
private IEnumerable<Person> _people;

public IEnumerable<Person> People()
{
    HashSet<T> hashSet;
    using (var new Scope())
    {
        // load a filter from somewhere else (oversimplified here to a single literal objects of an anonymous type)
        hashSet = new []
        {
            new { FirstName = "Boaty", LastName = "McBoatface" },
        }.ToHashSet();
    }
    using (var new AnotherScope())
    {
         return _people.Where(x => hashSet.Contains(new { FirstName = x.Nombre, LastName = x.Apellido }));
    }
}
```

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx): You create anonymous types by using the new operator together with an object initializer. So no, there is no other way.

Comment: How would it be anonymous if you define it ?

Comment: I don't want to give it a name (otherwise I'd create a struct as suggested by one of the answers below) I just want to ensure the same type is used for all entries in the HashSet.

Comment: Note that for this particular example you could just use string instead of the anonymous type

Comment: @Jono Although this requirement is really strange the way to already described in your solution seems to be the only one.

Comment: If you need to create several instances of the HashSet, you can make it a little easier by storing the empty enumerable in a variable. Then you can call `variable.ToHashSet()`. Or you can write a function. But the only way to create an anonymous type is to create an instance of it.

Comment: The code you wrote in the edit is totally messed up.

Comment: @Dennis_E it should be fixed now. What I'm trying to do is declare the type parameter T to be congruent with the anonymous type. I know that the second example does not compile. That is my problem.

Comment: @Jono No. With "messed up" I mean wrong. `using (var new Scope())` wasn't valid to begin with. And now you wrote `new [] { hashSet.Add(new {...etc` You mean `new [] { new { ...etc`

Comment: Moreover when defining your hashset as `HashSet<T>` you can only add instances of type `T`, not instances of any anonymous one.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis_E, that _is_ what I meant.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, the <code>T</code> is what I'd like to somehow get out of my code, and _yes_ I get the point that **naming it** is essentially requiring it to not be anonymous. My question, as poorly formed as it is, remains "how do I declare that type, keep it anonymous, and without creating an instance of it". I believe the answer is that I cannot.

Comment: See my edit on my answer from MSDN.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact there is no way of doing this, an anonymous object *always* has some object-initialization (which is by using `new`).

Anonymous types are some kind of set and forget, which means use them once - usually within a short piece of code e.g. a LINQ-expression- and then forget that they ever existed.

However you should ask yourself why you need this at all. When you need your list throughin your class give its entites a name. What do you gain by using the same anonymous type in different scopes? Be clear and precise. Thus every developer understands what your list contains and what he/she can accept from it.

So you´d better be off using a (private) `struct` for this which can also be used within your method.

```
class CyClass
{
    private struct Person { public string Name; }
    
    HashSet<Person> hashSet = new HashSet<Person>();

    ...

        using (var firstScope = new Scope())
        {
            hashSet.Add(new Person { Name = "Boaty" });
            hashSet.Add(new Person { Name = "McBoatface" });
        }
    
        using (var secondScope = new AnotherScope())
        {
            return names.Where(x => hashSet.Contains(new Person{ x.Name }));
        }
}
```

[MSDN clearily states this:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397696.aspx)

> If you must store query results or pass them outside the method boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct or class instead of an anonymous type

However I won´t limit this to method-boundaries as described within my second paragraph.

EDIT: To answer your question if it´s possible to create an anonymous type without instantiating it, see this sentence also from MSDN:

> You create anonymous types by using the new operator together with an
> object initializer

EDIT2: As of C#7 you can use a tuple in your list. However a tuple has at least two properties, so your first example won´t work here:

```
var myList = new List<(string FirstName, string LastName)>();
myList.Add(("Boaty", "McBoatface"));
```

Now you can check if your other list contains such a tuple:

```
var contained = anotherList.Contains(("Boaty", "McBoatface"));
```

Comment: Your answer implies that I should not use an anonymous type at all, rather that I should declare my own named type. My code sample was admittedly quite simple, but this type is not shared between methods; in fact it's only really used a few times within a single method and all usages are within about 5 lines of each other. I would prefer to stick to the anonymous type. It enables the first scope to populate the HashSet from Entity Framework, for example.

Comment: See my second paragraph.

Comment: I am using it once. I populate the values (in one scope) and then use them (in the second scope). This is within a single method (see my first comment). I feel this is the correct usage of an anonymous type, though I do realise that I want to bend the rules slightly from the most common scenarios.

Comment: @Marcel I don't get your point. What do you mean by "the" anonymous type?

Comment: I think the answer is wrong with respect to the anonymous type. It *is* possible to create initial variables of them. See my other answer.
Nevertheless I agree to the recommendation to use ValueTuples instead where possible. Unfortunately some LINQ providers (e.g. ORMs) do not support them.

Answer (score 2):

**You can create variables of an anonymous type without creating an instance of this type.**

```cs
public static T DefaultReturnValue<T>(this Action<T> _) => default;

var initialVariable = DefaultReturnValue(() => new { Name = "x" });
```

The action from the lambda is never executed. `DefaultReturnValue` just extracts the return type.

You can assign values to this variable later.

```cs
initialVariable = new { Name = "y" };
```

Using this for the second example in the OP the initial HashSet variable can be declared *without creating a superfluous instance* of the HashSet:

```
var hashSet = DefaultReturnValue(() => new [] { new { Name = (string)null } }.ToHashSet());
```

Comment: I don't see how that's different (code-wise) than the OP's initial proposal. You're still defining a "dummy" instance in code; the fact that it's never actually created is not relevant IMHO

Comment: @DStanley It's not only irelevant but pretty ugly, IMHO.